# System.FormatException received when while loop added to console calculator

Tags: c#, exception, while-loop

I am making a console calculator  in C# which asks the user to input 2 numbers and a character.

Here's the code:

```
using System;

namespace Calculator
{
    public static class Calculator
    {
        public static void welcome()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Calculator!");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        public static void printResult(int result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Answer: {result}");
        }

        public static void calculate(int num1r, char operr, int num2r)
        {
            int result_b = 0;
            switch(operr)
            {
                case '+':
                    result_b = num1r + num2r;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    result_b = num1r - num2r;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    result_b = num1r * num2r;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    result_b = num1r / num2r;
                    break;
            }
            printResult(result_b);

        }

        public static void askUser()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
            string str1 = Console.ReadLine();
            int num1 = (int)Convert.ToInt32(str1);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter another number: ");
            string str2 = Console.ReadLine();
            int num2 = (int)Convert.ToInt32(str2);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter an operator: ");
            char oper = (char)Console.Read();

            Console.WriteLine();

            calculate(num1, oper, num2);
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            welcome();
            askUser();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, the console looks something like this:

```
Welcome to Calculator!

Enter a number:
23424
Enter another number:
5232
Enter an operator:
+

Answer: 28656
```

I want to add a while loop so it can ask the user multiple times for inputs, if the user wants it to. So I added a little more code to this program:

```
using System;

namespace Calculator
{
    public static class Calculator
    {
        public static void welcome()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Calculator!");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        public static void printResult(int result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Answer: {result}");
        }

        public static void calculate(int num1r, char operr, int num2r)
        {
            int result_b = 0;
            switch (operr)
            {
                case '+':
                    result_b = num1r + num2r;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    result_b = num1r - num2r;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    result_b = num1r * num2r;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    result_b = num1r / num2r;
                    break;
            }
            printResult(result_b);

        }

        public static void askUser()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
            string str1 = Console.ReadLine();
            int num1 = (int)Convert.ToInt32(str1);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter another number: ");
            string str2 = Console.ReadLine();
            int num2 = (int)Convert.ToInt32(str2);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter an operator: ");
            char oper = (char)Console.Read();

            Console.WriteLine();

            calculate(num1, oper, num2);
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool bool1 = true;
            while (bool1 == true)
            {
                welcome();
                askUser();
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue?(y/n only) ");
                switch(Console.Read())
                {
                    case 'y':
                        Console.WriteLine("Ok!");
                    break;
                    case 'n':
                        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using Calculator!");
                        bool1 = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But now I get an exception:

```
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
```

And it points to the line `int num1 = (int)Convert.ToInt32(str1);`

For more information, I am using Visual Studio.

Comment: Hint: your next diagnostic step would be to find out the value of `str1`. You could do that by running in the debugger, or by adding more diagnostic console output. I strongly suspect that it includes the return that you pressed after the y/n only part... your `Console.Read()` only reads a single character.

Comment: I'd also very strongly recommend researching .NET naming conventions and starting to follow them right from the start - it's easier than trying to "unlearn" a bad habit.

Comment: Take note that you don't need to cast `(int)Convert.ToInt32()`, it's already returning an `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to some changes like this:

```
using System;

namespace Calculator
{
public static class Calculator
        {
            public static void welcome()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Calculator!");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            public static void printResult(int result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Answer: {result}");
            }

            public static void calculate(int num1r, char operr, int num2r)
            {
                int result_b = 0;
                switch (operr)
                {
                    case '+':
                        result_b = num1r + num2r;
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        result_b = num1r - num2r;
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        result_b = num1r * num2r;
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        result_b = num1r / num2r;
                        break;
                }
                printResult(result_b);

            }

            public static void askUser()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
                string str1 = Console.ReadLine();
                int num1 = (int)Convert.ToInt32(str1);

                Console.WriteLine("Enter another number: ");
                string str2 = Console.ReadLine();
                int num2 = (int)Convert.ToInt32(str2);

                Console.WriteLine("Enter an operator: ");
                char oper = Console.ReadLine()[0];

                Console.WriteLine();

                calculate(num1, oper, num2);
            }

            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                bool bool1 = true;
                while (bool1 == true)
                {
                    welcome();
                    askUser();
                    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue?(y/n only) ");
                    var continueSt = Console.ReadLine();
                    switch (continueSt)
                    {
                        case "y":
                        case "Y":
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using Calculator!");
                            bool1 = false;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Bye!");
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }
    }
}
```